# Wrong type argument: undo-tree, [cl-struct-undo-tree [nil ([nil ([nil nil ]]]

Tags: undo-tree-mode

The way I installed `undo-tree`:

- M-x `package-install` `undo-tree`

My setup:

- GNU Emacs 26.3
- undo-tree          0.7.4         installed  Treat undo history as a tree

```
(global-undo-tree-mode 1)
(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)
(setq undo-tree-history-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/undo")))
```

---

Error I am getting:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/netlab/.emacs’:

Wrong type argument: undo-tree, [cl-struct-undo-tree [nil ([nil ([nil nil ((q . -1) (undo-tree-id0 . -1) 2) nil (24247 15636 187465 670000) 0
nil]) ((1 . 2) (t 24232 5976 416148 754000)) nil (24247 15636 187476 578000) 0 nil]) nil nil (24247 15636 187481 124000) 0 nil] [nil nil ((q .
-1) (undo-tree-id0 . -1) 2) nil (24247 15636 187465 670000) 0 nil] 41 2 nil]

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I am not sure how can I fix this error or what causing it.

---

#### Update:

Output of the debug output:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument undo-tree [cl-struct-undo-tree [nil ([nil ([nil nil (... ...
2) nil (24247 15636 187465 670000) 0 nil]) ((1 . 2) (t 24232 5976 416148 754000)) nil (24247 15636 187476 578000)
0 nil]) nil nil (24247 15636 187481 124000) 0 nil] [nil nil ((#("q" 0 1 (fontified t)) . -1) (undo-tree-id0 . -1)
2) nil (24247 15636 187465 670000) 0 nil] 41 2 nil])
  signal(wrong-type-argument (undo-tree [cl-struct-undo-tree [nil ([nil ([nil nil ... nil ... 0 nil]) ((1 . 2) (t
24232 5976 416148 754000)) nil (24247 15636 187476 578000) 0 nil]) nil nil (24247 15636 187481 124000) 0 nil]
[nil nil ((#("q" 0 1 (fontified t)) . -1) (undo-tree-id0 . -1) 2) nil (24247 15636 187465 670000) 0 nil] 41 2
nil]))
  undo-tree-load-history(nil noerror)
  undo-tree-load-history-from-hook()
  run-hooks(find-file-hook)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer __init__.py> "~/folder/__init__.py" nil nil "~/folder/__init__.py"
(29887794 2050))
  find-file-noselect("/home/alper/folder/__init__.py")
  mapcar(find-file-noselect ("/home/alper/folder/Driver.py" "/home/alper/folder/__init__.py"
"/home/alper/folder/config.py" "/home/alper/folder/end_code.py"
"/home/alper/folder/garbageCollector.py" "/home/alper/folder/imports.py"
"/home/alper/folder/ipfs_daemon.py" "/home/alper/folder/lib.py" "/home/alper/folder/link.py"
"/home/alper/folder/setup.py" "/home/alper/folder/start_code.py"
"/home/alper/folder/thread_log.py" "/home/alper/folder/utils.py"
"/home/alper/folder/whisper_state_receiver.py"))
  find-file-noselect("*.py" nil nil t)
  find-file("*.py" t)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/alper/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 25178
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/alper/.emacs" "/home/alper/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x2967a1>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

---

#### desktop output:

- https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/8f310c9d8eda99815ad7153d89b6d108

Comment: If you remove the offending undo-tree saved history file relating to a buffer that Emacs is trying to open during startup, does Emacs start up properly?  Another thing to check would be your desktop saved history file to see if it is storing undo-tree stuff relating to an open buffer -- if so, then try removing the desktop save history file and try restarting.

Comment: `~.emacs.d/undo` is empty. I am not sure which file should I remove and where is it located. This occurs when I try to open a empty file as well. Also where is `desktop save history file` located?

Comment: If you are using the `desktop.el` save library to automatically load your last used layout, then evaluating the *function* `desktop-full-file-name` should tell you where it is located.  E.g., `M-x eval-expression RET (desktop-full-file-name) RET` assuming that the `desktop.el` library has already been loaded.  It should be somewhere in your `user-emacs-directory`, but could be elsewhere ...

Comment: Did you try invoking emacs with `emacs --debug-init` as suggested in the message? If that gives you a backtrace, please add it to your question.

Comment: See the debugging line near the top:  `find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer __init__.py> "~/folder/__init__.py" nil nil "~/folder/__init__.py"
(29887794 2050))`  And just above that is a call to `undo-tree-load-history`; and, then the error.  Perhaps `undo-tree` is looking in that folder where the `__init__.py` is located and finding a previously saved history file, and when it loads that history file you get the error.  Check that folder out and see what's there -- look for a history file.  And, also check again the undo-tree folder where you think the saved history files should be stored ...

Comment: Why are you opening all those python  files from your init file? What happens if you don't and you open them later interactively? In particular, what happens when you open `/home/alper/folder/__init__.py` later interactively? That seems to go off the rails in the backtrace.

Comment: The doc-string for `undo-tree-history-alist` states in part:  "*If this variable is nil, or it fails to match a filename, the backup is made in the original file's directory*"

Comment: Actually I have no idea why `__init__.py` file keep pops up I never open it, its is always empty. Probably `mypy` opens it on the background to detect the links between modules using `elpy-goto-definition`

Comment: My undo-tree history saved file looks like this:  `/Users/HOME/.emacs.d/undo/.!Users!HOME!Desktop!__init__.py.~undo-tree~`  Move that file to a *different* directory for potential deletion later, and then restart Emacs.

Comment: Ah all were hidden files, `__init__` contained the error message itself. Removing the file fixed the issue :-)
`cat .\!home\!user\!folder\!__init__.py.\~undo-tree\~` => `[cl-struct-undo-tree [nil ([nil (#1=[nil nil ((#("q" 0 1 (fontified t)) . -1) (undo-tree-id0 . -1) 2) nil (24247 15636 187465 670000) 0 nil]) ((1 . 2) (t 24232 5976 416148 754000)) nil (24247 15636 187476 578000) 0 nil]) nil nil (24247 15636 187481 124000) 0 nil] #1# 41 2 nil]%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few years ago, I created a fork of `undo-tree` that was compatible with Emacs 25 (but not later/newer versions of Emacs) and I spent a considerable amount of time debugging in relation thereto.  As part of that work, I inspected and debugged countless `undo-tree` saved history files -- that prior work helped me to identify the initial cursory debugging message and *guess*-timate the problem.  Initial attempts at troubleshooting the problem in the comments underneath the question above were complicated because the O.P. had suppressed visibility of hidden files in the `undo-tree` saved history file directory, and the O.P. was under the initial misimpression that the directory was empty. It turned out that the saved `undo-tree` history file was indeed where it was supposed to be, just hidden from view.  Deleting that file resolved the issue.  It is possible to spend additional time trying to ascertain why the `undo-tree` saved history file became problematic, but we will leave that issue for another question at some point in the future (should the need arise).

@NickD requested a lengthier backtrace as suggested by the initial cursory debugging message; i.e., "*Start Emacs with the `--debug-init` option to view a complete error backtrace.*"  And once the O.P. provided that detailed backtrace, it became crystal clear where the problem was as mentioned hereinabove.